# ASP.NET Themes samples/starter kits

Tags: asp.net, themes, sample, starter-kits

I was wondering if there was somewhere I could get some starter kit / theme sample for ASP.NET.

I am not a designer, but I need to build a prototype for a project, and if I do it myself it'll certainly be awful

Do you know where I could find that (ASP.NET specific)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check http://asp.net. There are quite a few starter kits and sample projects there. (http://www.asp.net/community/projects/)

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean templates for a website? If so, that is nothing to do with ASP.NET, There are loads of places to get decent free website templates including:

- http://www.templateworld.com/free_templates.html
- http://www.styleshout.com/
- http://www.freecsstemplates.org/

If you are after ASP.NET code snippets & samples, try:

- http://www.freevbcode.com/listcode.asp?Category=16
- http://www.asp101.com/

What specifically is your project concerned with?

Comment: The platform does matter some.  Many of these free templates are for Wordpress or similar blogging sites.  The class names and everything at tailored to the platforms.  I know ASP.NET pages don't have any inherent structure to them, but it'd be nice if there were some sample ASP.NET master pages and matching themes that can make a blog or a business application project look nice from the start instead of the underwhelming blandness we all usually make that betrays the awesome functionality displayed.

Comment: ... ASP.NET applications don't as often lend themselves, in my opinion, to blog-like sites.  Instead it's often used for those business applications which should have a greater information density than the airy blog templates.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/asp.net/aa336613.aspx). Asp.net specific design templates from msdn.

Answer (score 1):

you can check latest [Employee Info Starter Kit](http://eisk.codeplex.com/releases/view/61932) ASP.NET project template, which utilized some great css and jQuery frameworks and integrated with ASP.NET server controls.

Answer (score -2):

I advice to check ASP.NET Iteration Zero: http://aspnetzero.com/

It's a professional starter kit based on a strong framework and UI. It includes role and membership management and much more. You can create a demo to see it in action easily.

Comment: Please add a disclaimer when you are the creator of something.