# Looking for these specific website themes

Tags: css, templates, web

I'm looking to skin my web app according to different themes. So I guess I'm looking for some CSS designs?

It would be of great help if I could get any links to themes that resemble:

- Desert/sandstone/Middle East
- Green/environment/climate change
- Corporate
- Plain white background (Mac-ish look)
- Pastel/funky/marketing

I need the desert/sandstone/Middle East theme.

Comment: This question is seeking external resources, so is off-topic. I'll try to close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one's desert-like and could fit the Mid-East thing.

http://www.elegantthemes.com/preview/EarthlyTouch/

Answer (score 10):

- [Open Source Web Design](http://www.oswd.org/)
- [Open Source Templates](http://www.opensourcetemplates.org/)
- [Open Designs](http://www.opendesigns.org/)
- [Template Monster](http://www.templatemonster.com/)
- [Template World](http://www.templateworld.com)

Answer (score 1):

[Themeforest](http://themeforest.net/category/site-templates/admin-skins) has an "Admin skins" category -- they are a better fit for web application layout than random site designs.

Answer (score 0):

Not the same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139487/asp-net-themes-samples-starter-kits), but some of the answers may be useful to you

For example:

- http://www.templateworld.com/free_templates.html
- http://www.styleshout.com/
- http://www.freecsstemplates.org/

Answer (score 0):

[css Zen Garden](http://www.csszengarden.com/)

One html, dozens of CSS stylesheets.

[EDIT] This site demonstrates how to set up your HTML so it is easily styled and it gives you lots of examples how to achieve certain effects using CSS.

It's more suitable for designers than for "off the bench" pickers.

Comment: I'm not sure why this gets upvoted, it's not a template gallery or css theme library, rather "a demonstration of what can be accomplished visually through CSS-based design".

Comment: Probably just the impressive looks of the site.

Comment: Yes, downvote it everyone. sif I didn't already know about CSS Zen Garden.

Comment: I beg your pardon? Please remember that answers aren't for you only. :(

Comment: ON a positive note.  With enough downvotes, you can earn the peer pressure badge by deleting the entry. :D